# MYSQL Select only x_id that share the same y_id

Tags: mysql, sql

So for example, I have table with the content like this :

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | name_id   | type_id  | 
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |     1     |     1    | 
|  2 |     1     |     2    | 
|  3 |     1     |     3    | 
|  4 |     1     |     4    | 
|  6 |     2     |     1    | 
|  7 |     2     |     2    | 
|  8 |     3     |     1    | 
|  9 |     3     |     2    | 
|  10|     3     |     3    |
|  11|     4     |     1    | 
|  12|     4     |     2    |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I need a query that returning only the name_id that share the same type_id value from a set of name_id.

For example, I need name_id that share type_id with a set of name_id (1,2,3)
, the query will return name_id 2 because only name_id 2 have the same type_id from name_id 1 and 3

This looks simple, but I'm too stupid to figure it out. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If I right inderstood

```
select * from table where type_id=name_id and type_id in (1,2,3)
```